# Ember-cli-simple-auth - 'Cannot call method 'included' of undefined'

Tags: ember.js

My App is fully functional on my other computer, with authentication and everything, thus ember-simple-auth seems not to be the issue.
However, after a git pull and setting everything up with npm/bower install, when I try to run the server I get the following error:

```
version: 0.0.40
Cannot call method 'included' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot call method 'included' of undefined
    at Class.module.exports.included (/var/www/ember_sindico/node_modules/ember-cli-simple-auth/index.js:5:17)
    at EmberApp.<anonymous> (/var/www/ember_sindico/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:172:13)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at EmberApp._notifyAddonIncluded (/var/www/ember_sindico/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:170:23)
    at new EmberApp (/var/www/ember_sindico/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:165:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/ember_sindico/Brocfile.js:5:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I have a feeling I forgot to do something important but I'm really lost on this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Simple Auth's Ember CLI Addons now require Ember CLI 0.0.44: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-cli-simple-auth#installation

Comment: Thank you so much! Coincidentally the upgrade happened while I was changing the work environment on my pc. So I was going nuts.